# How to display loader until images will be displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a gallery, the structure of a thumbnail is like this:

```
<div style="background-image: _URL_FOR_THE_IMAGE;">
  <div class="ajax_loader"></div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".ajax_loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

But the problem is that the loader will never disappear.

How to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: And you're not testing this in jsFiddle, but on an actual site where window.onload fires.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is properly included. And yes.

Comment: `alert(1)` into `onload`? Something happens?

Comment: Try the native way, `window.onload = function() { $(".ajax_loader").fadeOut("slow"); }`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S2fdS/ double check everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Image class like so:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // code to remove loader and display image
}
img.src = IMAGE_URL;
```

This way you get an event when the images gets loaded, and is saved in the browser's cache.